# Encoding issues when uploading a file (HTML / Javascript)

Tags: file-upload, filereader

I have a input file form field for images. When the form is submitted (via axios) the file is always corrupted.

Even when logging the file contents to the console using the FileReader Browser Api the result has encoding issues (question mark on black square).

This is the content of the original file:
[image]

This is the file content of what is being read by the browser:
[image]

It seems like this is just an encoding issue but I really don't know where the problem should be.

Here is a very basic example of the code I am using. When I submit the form data to a php endpoint or Contentful the fiel data is wrong (as in the second screenshot).

```
<input type='file' accept='image/*' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
<script>
  var openFile = function(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    var file = input.files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
      console.log(reader.result);
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot read an image file as text, you can read it as an array buffer or a data URL.

Comment: Actually reading it as data url brings up the same issue. When converting the data url to binary (in node) the same happens.

Comment: The real solution is to not use FileReader and upload it as multipart/form-data and use 
multer in node to process it